# Customizing the payload of a JWT token in a MEAN stack application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

In my web application, a user signs in and a token is created. Now i want to add a claim to the payload of this token: a boolean value for being an admin or not.

I've searched around the web, but i can't seem to find how to implement this in a Mean stack application.

My goal is when a user signs in, i can check if the user is an admin using the payload of the token. Then i can lock specific parts of my application so they are only accessible for admins.

This is the login function in the service

```
function logIn(user) {
        return $http.post('/api/users/login', user, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getToken()
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            saveToken(data.token);
        }).error(function(err){
          return err;
        });
    }
```

These are the functions to save the token and get the token from local storage:

```
function saveToken(token) {
        $window.localStorage['ptlab-app-token'] = token;
    }
function getToken() {
        return $window.localStorage['ptlab-app-token'];
    }
```

And this is the function i use to check if a user is logged in in order to unlock specific parts of the application:

```
function isLoggedIn() {
        var token = getToken();

        if (token) {
            var payload = angular.fromJson($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));
            return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So i want to do sort of the same as isLoggedIn with the admin check. But i can't seem to figure out how to customize the payload of the jwt token and add a claim to the payload. With a claim called "admin", i can easily check if the user is and admin without having to access the database.

Has anybody got any suggestions ?

Comment: One note: I'm generally very biased when dealing with storing JWTs on cookies vs local/sessionStorage so I felt compelled to make sure you are aware of the differences from a security standpoint: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens :) cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the payload for the token upon its creation (in Node.js), so you can simply add a `isAdmin` boolean. Afterwards you can decode the token and retrieve the value of `isAdmin` to see if the user is an admin or not.

Token creation:

```
const payload = {
  id: user._id,
  isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
};
const token = jwt.sign(payload, "superSecret", {
  expiresIn: 86400,
});
```

Token decoding:

```
const decoded = await jwt.verify(token, "superSecret");
const isAdmin = decoded.isAdmin;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may simply go to JWT.io decode your token and find the content and even you can send the isAdmin Key and value in token decode and verify it on client side in node it is jwt.decode and same in angular application.